# ASP.NET Pikaday don't work with master page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, datepicker, pikaday

In a simple web form Pikaday works nice but when I'm using this in a content page it doesn't work, for better understanding I'm giving the code......Thanks in advance

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="Test2.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/pikaday.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and content page code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ContentPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test2.WebForm2" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h4>This is from content page</h4>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxFromDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="tbxToDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var picker1 = new Pikaday({
                    field: document.getElementById('tbxFromDate'),
                    theme: 'dark-theme'
                });
                var picker2 = new Pikaday({
                    field: document.getElementById('tbxToDate'),
                    theme: 'dark-theme'
                });
            </script>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

I don't understand what I'm missing

Comment: I don't understand what "doesn't work" means. Describe the behavior you are seeing, and describe the behavior you expected to see. Are there any server side errors? Any client side JavaScript errors in the console? If you set a breakpoint in your code, is it reached? When you inspect the resulting HTML in the browser, does everything, including element ID's, match what you were expecting? Please keep in mind, these are the sorts of details you need to include in your question, in the beginning, without being asked, in order to have a complete question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tbxFromDate` and `tbxToDate` do not exist in the HTML. Because the Controls are in a Content Control, their ID's are changed to ensure there are no duplicates.

Their ID probably looks something like this: `ContentPlaceHolder1_tbxFromDate`.

So you need to reference them by their `ClientID`. So use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var picker1 = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('<%= tbxFromDate.ClientID %>'),
        theme: 'dark-theme'
    });
    var picker2 = new Pikaday({
        field: document.getElementById('<%= tbxToDate.ClientID %>'),
        theme: 'dark-theme'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: If I were you, I would have held off on posting an answer until the question 1) clearly described what "doesn't work" and 2) showed an attempt at basic debugging. Learning how to do basic debugging and ask a good question will do them far more good in the long run than being handed the answer.

Comment: It works nice and sorry for this time for my mistake can I edit this post now?